# Do not allow specific sub/macro to be run

Tags: excel, vba

Quick question - is there a way where I can stop a certain macro (and not others) from showing up on the alt-f8 screen as well as simply disallowing a certain sub from being run? I have a sub that is a smaller part of another program that would not make sense to use alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if making it **private** makes sense in your context, it definitely solves your issue

```
Private Sub test()
MsgBox "cant see me "
End Sub

Public Sub hello()
MsgBox "see me"
End Sub
```

only hello is shown on pressing **Alt+F8**

Comment: Ok - thank you! I've never used private vs public in VBA yet, but this definitely makes sense.